# Rails nested resource route on column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a model named `Product`, which has a field named `category`.
How do I make a nested resourceful routing for the `Product` model using the `category` field?
e.g.:

```
/category1/ --> index products with 'category = category1'
/category2/13 --> show product '13' with 'category = category2'
/categories/ --> show overview of categories
```

Comment: I hope my question is of decent quality; New on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be fine doing:

```
resources :products do
  resources :categories
end
```

Then you get route helpers like `new_product_category_path` and your product categories would be accessible at a URL like `/products/:id/category/:id`

The 'Rails' way of doing it would be in product.rb:
`has_many :categories`.
For this to work you need a `category_id` column in your products table

And in category.rb
`belongs_to :product`

All this assumes that a product has only one category. If not, you'll have to set up a join table, in which case you should take a look at the docs on `has_many` through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know you would have to do each route manually like

```
get   '/:category/',         to: "products#index"
get   '/:category/:id',      to: "products#show"
get   '/:category/new',      to: "products#new"
get   '/:category/:id/edit', to: "products#edit"
match '/:category/:id',      to: 'products#create', via: :post
match '/:category/:id',      to: 'products#update', via: [:put, :patch]
match '/:category/:id',      to: 'products#destroy', via: :delete
```

for your first example `/category1/` will set the `params[:category]` to be `"category1"` in the controller

for your second example `/category2/13` will set the `params[:category]` to `"category2"` and `params[:id]` to 13 in the controller